# Getting connection refused error from one docker container to another only for REST request

Tags: docker, spring-boot, docker-network

I've two docker containers apiserver and loginserver. Both of them are provide REST API and are built using spring boot. I've created a bridge network called my-network and both the containers are attached to the same bridge. 
I pinged loginserver from apiserver via interactive shell and it is accessible. I make REST request from the host machine so I know the socket exposed. But, when I make the same REST request from apiserver to loginserver, I am getting error:

```
: HttpQueryService::uri=http://172.28.0.7:8090/users/login
2018-06-19 19:08:24.196 ERROR 7 --- [nio-9000-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 172.28.0.7:8090 [/172.28.0.7] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Here are the details from my-network:

```
docker network inspect my-network

[
    {
        "Name": "my-network",
        "Id": "ef610688b58b6757cba57caf6261f7a1eaeb083798098214c4848cbb152cae26",
        "Created": "2018-04-21T00:19:46.918124848Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.28.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.28.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "71863d2f61789d4350fcabb1330b757500d5734a85c68b60eb1ac8f6f1e8344e": {
                "Name": "mymongo",
                "EndpointID": "717c8dbdc8993a70f9d3e97e549cb9784020b8e68e7a557c30b0818b4c9acb90",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1c:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.28.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "936447ce8325f3a7273a7fb462d75e55841a9ff37ccf27647831b3db1b8a1371": {
                "Name": "mypg",
                "EndpointID": "6a1a1b2f7852b89a9d2cb9b9abecdabd134849cd789c31613c7ddb91a4bc43d1",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1c:00:06",
                "IPv4Address": "172.28.0.6/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "ad03348dffaef3edd916d349c88e8adf6cf7d88dbc40f82dc2384dee826cfa83": {
                "Name": "myloginserver",
                "EndpointID": "fe22c2b5f57b7fe4776087972ffa5f7f089ca6a59fde2fa677848b3f238ea026",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1c:00:07",
                "IPv4Address": "172.28.0.7/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "c69bfbf9ccdc9e29e87d2847b5c2a51e9c232fb8d06635bcef0cdd1f7c66e051": {
                "Name": "apiserver",
                "EndpointID": "46e94a52d34670eb00448b1d39a0cc365b882ece790c9d868dcee04ad141d1ca",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1c:00:0b",
                "IPv4Address": "172.28.0.11/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Comment: Is port 8090 exposed by your loginserver image? For checking type in command `docker images` and then find the `ImageID` of your loginserver image.  Then enter command `docker inspect image {Login server image id}`. In the output check `ExposedPorts`

Comment: That was it! 8090 was not exposed. Please make it as an answer. I will accept it!

Answer (score 1):

Is port 8090 exposed by your loginserver image? For checking type in command

```
docker images
```

and then find the ImageID of your loginserver image. Then enter command

```
docker inspect image {Login server image id}
```

In the output check ExposedPorts if 8090 is exposed or not

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but I just fixed this on my system by setting the address to get the REST request from as the [public IP address](http://www.whatismyip.com):

eg: `http://217.114.203.196/myrequest`